# Get value from web document input element with VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am having difficult to retrieve value `300` from the input named `points`.

Here's my HTML and VBA code.

**HTML**:

```html
<td id="myPower_val_9" style="visibility: visible;">
    <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="300" name="points"></input>
</td>
```

**VBA**:

```vb
Dim ie As Object
Dim myPoints As String

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
  .Visible = 0
  .navigate "www.example.com"

   While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4 
   DoEvents
   Wend

End With

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = ie.document

myPoints = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).getElementById("myPoints").innerText)
Range("A1").Value = myPoints
```

Comment: Why would you expect that to work?

Comment: There is a similar html code in my work place. I needed to retrieve the value from an input type but i tried many times and just didn't work.

Comment: innerText will give you what's beteween the tags; that's not what you want.  You want the value of the "value" attribute.

Comment: so are you saying that if i change "innerText" to "value" it will solve the problem?

Comment: You probably need to change it to `.getAttribute("value")` or something like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### HTML Code

I'd try working out the code that manipulates the Document Object Model (DOM) in javascript in a web browser so you can make use of better web based debugging tools.

There are **several issues here** that a console or debugger could help out with:

- You want to get the element ID `myPoints` but in HTML it's just called `points`
- You want to get the element by ID, but you've only set the name property -
- As long as `name` is unique to the element, you don't need to search for a `td` first
- As you can see from `<input></input>`, input elements do not have `innerText` (the text inside the `><`). Instead they have a `value` attribute
- The element exposes it's attributes and other data through the properties on the object itself.  So you can check the input's value by just looking at `.value`

Here's a javascript example of what you're trying to do:

```js
var value = document.getElementsByName("points")[0].value;
console.log(value);
```

```html
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="300" name="points" />
```

Open the console (<kbd>F12</kbd>), and you should see `300`

#### VBA

To convert it to VBA code for Excel, just make sure you uses parentheses `()` for VB arrays instead of square brackets `[]` for JS arrays:

```vb
myPoints = Trim(Doc.getElementsByName("points")(0).Value)
```

That should work just fine.

#### References

Since I'm not sure at what point you're failing in VB, also make sure you have all the proper web references in place in your VBA script.

Go to Tools > References > and add "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and "Microsoft Internet Controls":

[image: References]

#### Demo

I created a [**demo in plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6UTb9kHRZ363Ivhh2BPE?p=preview) so there would be a live site to go against instead of example.com.

Paste the following code into excel and everything should work fine:

```vb
Public Sub GetValueFromBrowser()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim url As String
    Dim myPoints As String

    url = "http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/6UTb9kHRZ363Ivhh2BPE/"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
      .Visible = 0
      .navigate url
       While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
         DoEvents
       Wend
    End With

    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = ie.document

    myPoints = Trim(Doc.getElementsByName("points")(0).Value)
    Range("A1").Value = myPoints

End Sub
```

**Output**:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

Use a CSS selector to get the element of `input[name='points']`

You don't show enough HTML to know if this is the only on the page. The above says elements with `input` tag having attribute `name` whose value is `'points'`

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the CSS selector with `.querySelector` method of `document` for a single element; `.querySelectorAll` for a `nodeList` of all matching elements i.e. if there is more than one on the page and you get the one of interest by index.

```
Debug.Print ie.document.querySelector("input[name='points']").getAttribute("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.getAttribute("name of attribute")` to get an attributes value. In your case `.getAttribute("value")` will return 300.

```
Dim ie As Object
Dim myPoints As String

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
  .Visible = 1
  .navigate "website URL"

   While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
   DoEvents
   Wend

End With

Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set Doc = ie.document

myPoints = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).getElementsByTagName("input")(0).getAttribute("value"))
Range("A1").Value = myPoints
```

Just on a side note. I don't know much about HTML and maybe someone can elaborate on this more. But if you want to test that HTML code you need to add in the < table> < tr> tags. 
Something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="myPower_val_9" style="visibility: visible;">
            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="300" name="points"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```